# How can I differentiate between code block and normal string in string

Tags: angular

I am having one string as given below:

```
"explain this code \n dependencies {\n    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'\n    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.20'\n    implementation 'org.eclipse.lsp4j:org.eclipse.lsp4j:0.8.0'\n    //implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:1.4.0'\n    // runtimeOnly 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'\n    implementation 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'\n    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'\n    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'\n}"
```

Now in the above string, how can I differentiate between the normal string part and the code block as I want to highlight the code block with `highlight.js`.

I have tried using `highlight.js` but its highlights normal string as well.

Comment: Have you tried RegEx?

Comment: By code block you mean each substring within the ticks? `' ... '`?